# Linq GROUP BY and SUM nullable long

Tags: c#, linq, sum, nullable

Here is my code:

```
var Summary = ccL3.GroupBy(g => new
            {                    
                g.JOB_BASE_NUM,
                g.TOP_CUSTOMER_ID,
                g.TOP_DESCRIPTION

            })
               .Select(g => new Type2
               {                       
                   JOB_BASE_NUM = g.Key.JOB_BASE_NUM,
                   TOP_CUSTOMER_ID = g.Key.TOP_CUSTOMER_ID,
                   TOP_DESCRIPTION = g.Key.TOP_DESCRIPTION,
                   SUM_JOB1 = g.Sum(gs => gs.JOB1)                       
               })
```

EDIT:  This is not a duplicate.  The previous discussion cannot be directly used in GROUP BY.

JOB1 is nullable long.

The problem is that I need the SUM_JOB1 to be null if all JOB1 in ccL3 is null (It returns 0 if all is null or if the sum is 0).

I searched the following topics, but there is no discussion of SUM of null in GROUP BY in linq.  Can someone help me please.  Thank you.

Reference:
[handle null in linq sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766904/handle-null-in-linq-sum-expression)

[Linq query with nullable sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696431/linq-query-with-nullable-sum)

[Force linq sum to return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537079/force-linq-sum-to-return-null)

Comment: This answer to one of the questions you linked may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43537187/2169762

Comment: Also this one, which is an extension method to do exactly what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43537671/2169762.  Perhaps you should have looked thoroughly through the questions you linked in your own question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force linq sum to return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537079/force-linq-sum-to-return-null)

Comment: How do I use TrueForAll in my group by code?  I tried it with no success.it says IGrouping<type......> does not contain a definition of TrueForAll...

Comment: @MartinParkin I have tried to make this extension to work, wrote this NullableSum but in the group by, I put JOB1= g.NullableSum(gs => gs.JOB1)....it was just throw errors : No overload for method NullableSum to take 1 arguement....can you give an example of code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any item is not null, then use `Sum`, otherwise null

```
SUM_JOB1 = g.Any(gs => gs.JOB1 != null) ? g.Sum(gs => gs.JOB1) : null
```

Comment: Thank you. Such a simple solution!